# Porting Word2Vec's random number generation from C to torch

Tags: c, torch, word2vec

I am trying to port the following bit of C code (part of Word2Vec) to torch, and need to understand exactly what it does (I am not a computer scientist by training, so struggling with some aspects). I have the beginning of an answer, but if someone could confirm and complete my solution, that'd be great.

The code is the following. It is inside a while loop; the variable *sample* is a constant = 10^-3 and *next_random* is initialised to some thread number at the beginning of the function calling the code.

```
// The subsampling randomly discards frequent words while keeping the ranking same
    if (sample > 0) {
      real ran = (sqrt(vocab[word].cn / (sample * train_words)) + 1) * (sample * train_words) / vocab[word].cn;
      next_random = next_random * (unsigned long long)25214903917 + 11;
      if (ran < (next_random & 0xFFFF) / (real)65536) continue;
    }
```

My understanding is the following.

- *ran* produces some number which is a function of the frequency of a word in the processed text, and *train_words* the total number of tokens (previously smoothed by an alpha term, but let's ignore this).
- *next_random* is assigned a value by a function which looks like a Linear
  Congruential Generator. I am getting this information from here: http://www.public.iastate.edu/~mervyn/stat580/Notes/s09rn.pdf. Please correct if I'm wrong.
- *next_random* is masked to keep only the lowest 16 bits unchanged. So I now have a binary number with max (decimal) value 65535. Divided by 65536, this gives me a number between 0 and 1, which I can compare *ran* to.

Assuming my understanding is correct, I guess my main question here is whether I would do something wrong by simply using the torch inbuilt random number generator in place of the above code. I.e. would the following be as equivalent as possible to the original?

```
if sample > 0 then
   ran = (torch.sqrt(counts[word] / (sample * train_words)) + 1) * (sample * train_words) / counts[word]
   if ran < torch.random()/(2^32) then
      continue
   end
end
```

Thanks!